# File updates are not triggering recompile - New Create React App

Tags: webpack, babeljs, fsevents, watchman, chokidar

Did a fresh install of my mac with the following:

Mac OS: Catalina 10.15.4
Node: 10.12.1
npx: 6.14.4

Started with create-react-app. But not recompiling on js file changes. Tried sudo npm start as well.

Any pointers would be great. Have been at this for hours. Tried reinstalling node a bunch of times.

Comment: Its a new react app, so I am just modifying app.js and checking if that would trigger a recompile and update the browser. But it's not doing anything on save. Running `npm start` which translates to `react-scripts start`